# fetch Youtube video dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am trying to fetch video from you tube channel using react.js

I tried with PHP CURL and i get proper response. Below code display s blank page. 
Please help.

```
import $ from 'jquery'; 
import React, { Component } from 'react';;

class iLotIndex extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {video: []};
  }

VideoList() {
    return $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&channelId=UCexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20')
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ video : data.results });
      });
  }


  render() {
    this.VideoList().then(function(res){
      this.state = {video: res};
    });
    return (
      <div id="layout-content" className="layout-content-wrapper">
        <div className="panel-list">
          {this.state.video.map((item, i) =>{
            return(
              <h1>{item.items}</h1>

            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Is any error in your browser console?

Comment: can you provide fiddle? or pen or jsben.ch ?

Comment: Don't mix jQuery and React ;)

Comment: I will suggest superagent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `this.VideoList()` calling into `componentDidMount()` instead of `render()`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {video: []};
  this.VideoList = this.VideoList.bind(this);
}

VideoList() {
  fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&channelId=UCexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20')
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp);
      //this.setState({video: resp.results});
      this.setState({video: resp.items});
      console.log(this.state.video);
    });


  //$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&channelId=UCexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20')
    //.then((data) => {
      //this.setState({ video : data.results });
    //});
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.VideoList();
}

render() {

  return (
    <div id="layout-content" className="layout-content-wrapper">
      <div className="panel-list">
        {this.state.video.map((item, i) =>{
          console.log(item);
          return(
            <h1>{item.items}</h1>

          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Please post here some errors in case it doesn't work yet, thanks!

Comment: i can see response from youtube api in my console but it still not rendering any html on web page. can you please help ?

Comment: That maybe OK now, would you mind trying it again, thanks! Feel free to console.log the returned data and setState properly for your "video". I couldn't see the returned json structure so hopefully it will work this time ^^. I've just also fixed the correct "resp" variable name instead of the previous "data" one

Comment: It is saying this.state.video is undefined

Comment: Please also keep your constructor: constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {video: []};
  }

Comment: I put console.log(this.state.video) ; inside return . it does not print any log on console

Comment: Sorry, I've just modified it correctly so that you can console.log something now, could you please view your log again, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144065/discussion-between-nirali-joshi-and-thinhvo0108).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use axios or fetch with react

```
axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&channelId=UCexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20')
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({video: response.results})
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Also you are mutating the state directly when in the render function which your don't need since you are anyways setting the state. Also one more thing, I don't think you need to get the api response on every render, you can do that in `componentWillMount`, use `setInterval` if you want it to be periodic.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';;
import axios from 'axios';
class ILotIndex extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {video: []};
  }
componentWillMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
         this.VideoList();
    }, 2000)
}
VideoList() {
    axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&channelId=UCexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20')
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({video: response.results});
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div id="layout-content" className="layout-content-wrapper">
        <div className="panel-list">
          {this.state.video.map((item, i) =>{
            return(
              <h1>{item.items}</h1>

            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And a major mistake that you did is to define your React component, starting with a lower case character, they should always begin with uppercase otherwise transpiler will try to search them in the already defined tags like `div, p, span etc`

Comment: I do not have axios installed.can you please let me know that how can i install ?

Comment: In my opinion, this.VideoList() calling should be in componentDidMount(), so that we don't need to setTimeout, waiting for 2-3 seconds (setTimeout here may be dangerous because we don't know when the page finishes rendering). However, componentDidMount() makes sure the page has been rendered already

Comment: npm install -S axios

Comment: I will try to install. but i am getting response from api , so why it is not rendering on page? could you help me understand  {this.state.video.map((item, i) =>{
            return(
              <h1>{item.items}</h1>

            )
          })}

Comment: could you please console.log(this.state.video) after setting that state, and as I commented above, setTimeout in componentWillMount() maybe dangerous.

Comment: You can actually use either "axios" or "fetch", they're both fine anyway!

Comment: No @thinhvo0108, setInterval in componentWillMount is not dangerous at all, it all depends, as to how are you initialising you state, she has initialised with a empty array and so it should be fine.

Comment: Can you post the result of console.log(this.state.video) in render function

Comment: Yes, you may be right, a blank array will have nothing to be rendered, however, perhaps setInterval is a bit, in my opinion, unnecessary here since it doesn't need to repeat so many times here ^^ unless we have special puppose to execute the code again after that interval of time, I think